# TouchesMoved Lag with Pathfinding

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, lag, path-finding, touchesmoved

I'm making a game where the player follows a touch. The game has obstacles and pathfinding, and I'm experiencing extreme lag with touches moved. Upon loading the game, everything works, but after a few seconds of dragging my finger around (especially around obstacles) the game freezes to the point where moving a touch will freeze all physics (0 fps) until the touch is ended.

I'm assuming the culprit is my function `makeGraph()`, which finds a path for the player from `player.position:CGPoint()` to `player.destination:CGPoint()`, storing a path in `player.goto:[CGPoint()]`, the update function then takes care of moving to the next goto point.

This function is called every cycle of `touchesmoved`, so the player can switch directions if the finger moves over an obstacle

My question is: 1) what in this code is causing the unbearable lag,  2) how can I make this code more efficient?

My code:

initializing vars:

```
var obstacles = [GKPolygonObstacle(points: [float2()])]
var navgraph = GKObstacleGraph()
```

setting up a graph (called at start of level):

```
func setupGraph(){

    var wallnodes :[SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "wall") {
        node, stop in
        wallnodes.append(node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "crate") {
        node, stop in
        wallnodes.append(node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }

    obstacles = SKNode.obstacles(fromNodeBounds: wallnodes)
    navgraph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: obstacles, bufferRadius: Float(gridSize/2))

}
```

touchesmoved: I keep track of multiple touches using strings. only one finger may act as the "MoveFinger." this string is created at `touchesbegan` and emptied at `touchesended`

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchloop: for touch in touches {            

        if MoveFinger == String(format: "%p", touch) {                
            let location = touch.location(in: self)                
            player.destination = location
            makeGraph()
            player.moving = true
            player.UpdateMoveMode()                
            continue touchloop                
        }

        // .... more if statements .... 

    }
}
```

and graph function (called every touchesmoved cycle):

```
func makeGraph(){

    let startNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: float2(Float(player.position.x), Float(player.position.y)))
    let endNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: float2(Float(player.destination.x), Float(player.destination.y)))
    let graphcopy = navgraph
    graphcopy.connectUsingObstacles(node: startNode)
    graphcopy.connectUsingObstacles(node: endNode)
    let path = graphcopy.findPath(from: startNode, to: endNode)

    player.goto = []

    for node:GKGraphNode in path {
        if let point2d = node as? GKGraphNode2D {
            let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point2d.position.x), y: CGFloat(point2d.position.y))
            player.goto.append(point)
        }
    }

    if player.goto.count == 0 {
        //if path is empty, go straight to destination               
        player.goto = [player.destination]
    } else {
        //if path is not empty, remove first point (start point)
        player.goto.remove(at: 0)
    }

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: 1) Comparing strings will cause slowdown, you should find a better way around that. 2)  Yeah your makeGraph plan looks very very painful.  Your player .goto array looks like it is getting rebuilt every time.  I have not played around with Gameplay Kits path finding, but I do not think graph copy is doing a copy,  so you are constantly connecting the various start and end nodes to your navgraph.

Comment: Perfect! copying the graph was the problem. I added `        navgraph.remove([startNode, endNode])
` at end of the makegraph function and am running at 60fps. Thanks! i'd like to work around comparing strings but haven't found a better method of tracking multitouch.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can retain the touch object and use === to make sure the touch you are using is the one on MoveFinger.   Basically `var MoveFinger : UITouch?` and `MoveFinger = touch`

Comment: and how would I "empty" the touch or check if its empty? ie the equivalent of MoveFinger = "" or if MoveFinger != "" {}

Comment: it is optional, so you say `if let MoveFinger = MoveFinger, MoveFinger == touch`